# Error on update Customer invoice settings custom_fields Stripe

Tags: laravel, stripes

i'm tryng to update my Customer on Stripe with custom_fields but I receive this error:

> "Received unknown parameter: 1" on line 66 of Customer.php

In my customer class I have a function that tying to update customer:

```
\Stripe\Customer::update("stripe_id",
                [
                    ["address"=> ["line1"=>"address"]],
                    ["invoice_settings" => ["custom_fields" => ["name"=>"test", "value"=>"test"]]],
                    "email"=>"email@email.it"
                ]);
```

The problem is

> ["custom_fields" => ["name"=>"test", "value"=>"test"]]

because if I put an empty array as

> ["custom_fields" => []]

I have tried also with:

```
\Stripe\Customer::update("stripe_id",
                    [
                        ["address"=> ["line1"=>"address"]],
                        ["invoice_settings" => ["custom_fields" => [["name"=>"test", "value"=>"test"]]]],
                        "email"=>"email@email.it"
                    ]);
```

It updates my customer.

How should use custom_fields on Stripe?

Answer (score 2):

I Foun my error:

the problem Is that I should post data foramtted in this way:

```
\Stripe\Customer::update("stripe_id",
                    [
                        ["address"=> ["line1"=>"address"]],
            /**[*/      "invoice_settings" => ["custom_fields" => 
                         [["name"=>"test", "value"=>"test"]
           
                                               ]
                        ]/**]*/,
                        "email"=>"email@email.it"
                    ]);
```

So without wrapping invoice_settings on array.